# Is there a maximun number of edges/vertices PGRouting can cope with?

Tags: pgrouting

We have imported OSM networks to route on. So our IDs sometimes grow abnormally big ;)

It seems that PGRouting is failing with IDs like 633719916...

We got this error message from postgresql:
"terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'".

Is there another way rather than renumbering our IDs?

Is there a "fix" planned from PGRouting?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting [pgRouting mailing list](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/pgrouting-users/2010-December/000426.html):

> It's probably the ID being to large, yes. [...] So if your total number of road links is OK and it would fit with integer, then it's better to renumber ID's, because it will also affect calculation speed.

Comment: Yes this seems to be a well known problem, but no one seems to know what the limit is. There are also limits on the most number of links/nodes loaded at once: I have been unable to route across the US using OSM data, for example.

Comment: Well, the data type of source and target is 'bigint', so that's the theoretical limit. But in practice you should try to keep ID's low and without "wholes".